# How do I use More Like This API in Elasticsearch for ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I couldn't find any documentation about this at all. Or, maybe I'm missing something. I'm trying to use Elasticsearch's [More Like This API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html) with the `elasticsearch` gem.

I've indexed all documents already.

Here's my code:

```
require 'elasticsearch'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true

client.search index: 'movies', body: { query: { match: { description: 'test' } } }

client.search index: 'movies', body: { more_like_this: {
  fields: ['description'],
  like_text: 'Once upon a time' 
} }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Parse Failure [No parser for element [more_like_this]]];
>   }{[2fk_R7WbTky6UfMCbKPKGA][movies][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your `more_like_this` in `query`, like so:

```
client.search index: 'movies', body: {
  query: { 
    more_like_this: {
      fields: ['description'],
      like_text: 'Once upon a time' 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zoran, saves me, since could not make work "client.mlt".